# How does the Golden Condor take off and land?

Tags: mysterious-cities-of-gold

The 80s TV cartoon *The Mysterious Cities of Gold* depicts an ornithopter called [the Golden Condor](https://mcog.fandom.com/wiki/The_Golden_Condor). I love its design and have been trying to build my own small-scale replica using EPP foam, but I'm not sure what mechanism the real one uses to take off and land.

How does the Golden Condor take off and land? Does the show explain this?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how a real-life condor is able to take off and land? If so, that would be off-topic because it has nothing to do with science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @f1krazy It's an ornithopter. "The Golden Condor | Mcog Wiki | Fandom" https://mcog.fandom.com/wiki/The_Golden_Condor

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Then I think it might be on-topic, I'll edit the question and see if I can make it coherent.

Comment: For the original series, episode 19 shows it both landing and taking off - the legs descend as it lands, and it skids to a halt. Once stopped, it shifts into its landed form (the skids swivel to have the flat side down, it tilts up and the head and wingtips tilt down). When launching, it seems to thrust forwards to build speed like an aeroplane before lifting. It is solar powered, and can only fly in full sunlight. It basically has two forms - one in flight, and one landed - so you'll probably have to pick which you want for your model.

Comment: Eesh, only 2 MCOG questions on the site since 2012 and they are duplicates!